# Copy files listed in a txt file and put it in another directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, copy-paste

Im trying to copy multiples/hundreds of files using a text file and placing it in another directory
For example my source directory has this files.

```
09_yehey_123456.SENT
09_yohoo_987654.SENT
09_testy_789065.SENT
09_lolol_124125.SENT
09_hahah_241567.SENT
```

And the text file looks like this (this text file contains the files that I should only copy from the source directory)

```
09_yehey
09_yohoo
09_testy
```

Here's the code that i tried using

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (files2.txt) do echo F|xcopy "C:\Users\username\source\%%i*" "C:\Users\username\Documents\dest\%%i"
PAUSE
```

the * from the source dir doesnt seem to work as a wildcard

Comment: What is the intent of the `echo F|` in the command you're trying to run? (What are you expecting it to do?)

Comment: Im very quite new to batch files, and i've seen this used from some site, and i tried and it actually work if the filenames indicated on my txt file is same as the filenames in the source directory

Comment: @KenWhite - try to use xcopy with a single file - it will prompt you if you want to create a new directory.

Comment: @npocmaka: Ah. Got it. I've not seen it done like that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this  :

```
  for /f "delims=" %%i in (files2.txt) do (
     copy /y "C:\Users\username\source\%%~ni*" "C:\Users\username\Documents\dest\"
    )
    PAUSE
```

As the names in the text file are not the same as the actual files you'll need wild cards.

Comment: @XanderVane - the copy part or the for /f ?

Comment: i think it is the copy part since the files2.txt and the batch file  that i run is in the same directory

Comment: @XanderVane - what if you change copy with echo? is the file name printed?

Comment: it just shows the filename with 09_yehey*  but not the actual filename like 09_yehey_0812412.SENT

Comment: @XanderVane it's not supposed to print whole file name.COPY can use wildcards.

Comment: Oh i see but if i change it back to copy, it doesnt copy

Comment: It's fine now, i got confused with my paths, sorry and thank you very much you saved me a lot of time